# Is there a beard poster?

Tags: product-recommendation, beard

[image]
Here is a poster of the general areas and halachos of what is included in peyos. Does a similar thing exist for beards?

I’m imaging it would have red areas (agreed by all to be part of the beard) yellow (derabanan?) orange(minority opinions/chumras).

Would be helpful for those who don’t cut their beard at all but also for those who shave if they wanted to use a proper razor in order to get a closer cut in those areas that it would be allowed. 
I tried contacting the company that made the peyos one but they didn’t know.

Comment: You could make one yourself. It might not be any better than this one halakhically. Talk to your rabbi for rulings; don't get rulings from colorful posters.

Comment: So 4mm is still kein tar? Meh.